# VoronoiMesh with boundary edges removed

Tags: graphics, regions, computational-geometry, mesh

I would like to create a Voronoi diagram without the boundary edges highlighted.
This code

`gVD = VoronoiMesh[X, MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> {Thick, Red}}]`

produces the  1st image [left/top] (`X` is my set of sites). What I want is the 2nd image
[right/bottom], which I edited in Adobe Illustrator to remove the edges around the square.
I have been unsuccessful in identifying those boundary edges. Any ideas?

---

[image]
 
[image]

---

(Incidentally, these Voronoi diagrams have no interior cells: all cells are unbounded.)

---

```
X = {{1.60949, -3.71179}, {5.7819, -7.34439}, {9.88144, 8.31277}, 
  {8.30027, 13.0336}, {-10.5991, 10.1752}, {-6.70748, 1.50298}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VoronoiMesh[X, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{1, "Interior"} -> {Thick, Red}, {1, "Frontier"} -> {Thick, Red}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
VoronoiMesh[X, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{1, "Boundary"} -> Opacity[0], {1, All} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks so much! I was unaware of these keywords, "Boundary," "Frontier," "Interior."

Comment: @Joseph, yes, these are unfortunately undocumented. Please consider sending a suggestion to Support if you want these documented.